# Making a binary calculator app (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, binary, calculator

For a project in Uni I decided to make a binary calculator app to learn a little bit more about coding.

I've come as far as completing a regular calculator app (but it only has two numbers: 1 ; 0) but I can't figure out how to make the calculator work like it should ( 1010 + 1101 = 10111 not 2111). All help is appreciated.

```
var numberEkraanil:Double = 0;
var eelmineNumber:Double = 0;
var tehesmatemaatikat = false
var operation = 0;

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func Numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if tehesmatemaatikat == true
    {
        label.text = String(sender.tag-1)
        numberEkraanil = Double(label.text!)!
        tehesmatemaatikat = false
    }
    else
    {
        label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
        numberEkraanil = Double(label.text!)!
    }
}

@IBAction func nupud(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 6 && sender.tag != 8
    {
        eelmineNumber = Double(label.text!)!
        if sender.tag == 3 //Liitmine
        {
            label.text = "+";
        }
        else if sender.tag == 4 //Lahutamine
        {
            label.text = "-";
        }
        else if sender.tag == 5 // Korrutamine
        {
            label.text = "x";
        }
        else if sender.tag == 7 // Jagamine
        {
            label.text = "÷";
        }

        operation = sender.tag
        tehesmatemaatikat = true;
    }
    else if sender.tag == 8
    {
        if operation == 3
        {
          label.text = String(eelmineNumber + numberEkraanil)
        }
        else if operation == 4
        {
            label.text = String(eelmineNumber - numberEkraanil)
        }
        else if operation == 5
        {
            label.text = String(eelmineNumber * numberEkraanil)
        }
        else if operation == 7
        {
            label.text = String(eelmineNumber / numberEkraanil)
        }
    }
    else if sender.tag == 6
    {
        label.text = ""
        eelmineNumber = 0;
        numberEkraanil = 0;
        operation = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get signed integer from swift string of binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903221/get-signed-integer-from-swift-string-of-binary)

Comment: You need to convert your text input to binary digits, and the binary of your result to strings. 

I suggest reading up on base conversion. (A hint: Look at the binary bit shift operators `<<` and `>>` and the bitwise and operator `&&`.)

Comment: Any time you have a long construct of `if <condition> then <statement> else if <condition> then <statement> else if <condition>` you should look at using a different approach like a switch statement.

Comment: Also, tags are not a great way to handle different buttons. I suggest hooking up outlets to each button, and then comparing the sender to see which outlet it matches: `switch sender { case plusButton: <your_code> ; case minusButton: <your_code> }`

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly convert binary numbers to decimal numbers. For example turn "1010" into int "10" and then reverse the process to get the binary again. In your example "1010 + 1101 = 10111" you can convert "1010" and into "10" and "13", make the ordinary calculation with those decimals and convert the result "23", which will give you "23".

But of course there are other ways. This website can help you with binary calculation. It's a math website: http://www.calculator.net/binary-calculator.html.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a base 10 to base 2 and a base 2 to base 10 converter. Here is pseudo-code for both:

**To convert a binary string to an integer, do the following:**

- Seed a result value to zero.
- while your input string is not empty:

  - shift the result value 1 bit to the left
  - remove the left-most character from your input string, and if it's a 1, add 1 to your result value.

**To convert an int to a binary string, do the same in reverse:**

- Copy your int to a scratch variable, `scratch`.
- Set your output string to an empty string.
- While scratch is not 0:

  - if scratch && 1 is 0, append a "0" to the left of your output string
  - if scratch && 1 is 1, append a "1" to the left of your output string
  - shift scratch 1 bit to the right

Once you have those building-blocks getting your calculator to work is pretty straightforward. When the user inputs a binary string, convert it to an integer working value. Do your calculations on integer values, and then convert the integer result to a binary string for display.